# Read colors of image with Python (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, image, analysis

How can I read the colors of an image with python using google app engine?

**Example:** I like to build a function to determine the most striking colors of an image to set a harmonic background color for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Images API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/images/overview.html) does not (currently) contain pixel-level functions. To quote the overview document:

> Note: In order to use the Images API in your local environment you must first download and install PIL, the Python Imaging Library. PIL is not available on App Engine; it is only used as a stub for the Images API in your local environment. Only the transforms provided in the images API are available on App Engine.

The community has been asking for full [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm) support for some time, but it looks like we'll have to wait.

Answer (score 2):

For PNG you can use [PyPNG module](http://packages.python.org/pypng/) - lightweight pure-Python PNG decoder/encoder.

```
import png

point = (10, 20) # coordinates of pixel to read

reader = png.Reader(filename='image.png') # streams are also accepted
w, h, pixels, metadata = reader.read()
pixel_byte_width = 4 if metadata['has_alpha'] else 3
pixel_position = point[0] + point[1] * w
print pixels[
  pixel_position * pixel_byte_width :
  (pixel_position + 1) * pixel_byte_width]
```

Comment: Reading of other image types can be achieved by converting the image to PNG within AppEngine.

Comment: Can you use this module in GAE?

Comment: @papercuts, I don't see why not. Answers here seem to confirm this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431345/text-to-a-png-on-app-engine-python

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to put Flash or a Java applet on the page, you might be able to do it on the client. I'm not sure if anything like canvas or SVG supports pixel-level manipulation, but if they do, you might be able to get it to work in some browsers with JavaScript.

The Flash or Java Applet, can be invisible and optional -- you can use JavaScript to detect if the user has the plugin and only support this feature when they do.

Comment: That's assuming that the application is a website, it's possible it would be something else.